# Can't create text file when using Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, text-files

As title says, the file is not created when using servlets. I have a simple web application, and I want to take input from the HTML and write them down into a .txt file. The problem is that, everything runs good, and I don't get any error or exception, it just doesn't create the text file. I took the same code (for creating the text file) and I tested it into a separate class and it works perfectly. The problem is when I try to create a text file in the servlet. This is my code:

```
@WebServlet("/home")
public class HomePage extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.sendRedirect("/home.html");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String add = request.getParameter("buttonAdd");
        String read = request.getParameter("buttonRead");
        String update = request.getParameter("buttonUpdate");
        String delete = request.getParameter("buttonDelete");

        if(add != null)
        {
            String title = request.getParameter("dvd_title");
            String year = request.getParameter("dvd_year");
            String price = request.getParameter("dvd_price");

            if(!title.equals("") && !year.equals("") && !price.equals(""))
            {
                if(!Character.isDigit(title.charAt(0)))
                {
                    if (isNumeric(year) && isNumeric(price))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("Title: " + title, "Year: " + year, "Price: " + price);
                            Path file = Paths.get("DVD - " + title + ".txt");
                            Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                        }
                        catch(IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.setContentType("text/html");
                        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                        out.println("Year and price must be numbers");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    out.println("Title cannot start with a number");
                }
            }
        }

        if(read != null)
        {
            System.out.println("2");
        }

        if(update != null)
        {
            System.out.println("3");
        }

        if(delete != null)
        {
            System.out.println("4");
        }
    }

    private static boolean isNumeric(String s)
    {
        return s != null && s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run your code through a debugger, to make sure the lines of code creating the file are actually executed? Have you added logging statements to know? Have you printed the absolute file path and made sure you were looking at the right place?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes to all questions.

Comment: So, what is the absolute path of the file? And how about showing us the code you used to find out?

Comment: @JBNizet Ups, my mistake. Apparently, it creates the file in the Apache Tomcat folder. I got that using the absolute path. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it creates the file in the Apache Tomcat/bin folder, and not in the project folder. My mistake. Thanks JB Nizet for the help.